# In Grafana, how do I map labels from Prometheus to a different set of (more user-friendly) values?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a table/graph in Grafana, built from Prometheus data. It looks like this:

[image]

`instance_id` is a label in Prometheus, and you can see the values in the labels are integers, e.g. `10569`, `8891`, etc.

I want to map those integers to user-friendly values, so our non-technical users can understand the dashboard better. e.g. I want it to end up like this:

[image]

So when the value of the label is `10569`, it'll say `Paul`, and when the value of the label is `8891`, it'll say `Keith`, and etc. etc. etc. for all the other integer values.

Is there a way I can do this mapping in Grafana? I don't have the ability to alter the labels, *but* I could easily e.g. set up an XML or JSON endpoint or something that would give a map like:

```
10569: Paul
8891: Keith
etc. etc. etc.
```

Or even push that list into Grafana via CI/CD nightly potentially.

It looks like the Grafana plugin `Field lookup` is *almost* what I need... except that it only supports countries and currencies.

Is there a way to do this sort of mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Sort it on the metric source level:

a.) push that `name` label in that metric, so you can query and use it directly from Grafana

b.) sometimes additional `_info` metric is used, which has only "metadata" (e.g. name in your case). Then it can be used on the PromQL query level, where you join data metric query with metadata metric query, e.g.:

```
aws_ec2_cpuutilization_average 
+ 
on (name) group_left(tag_Name) aws_ec2_info
```

Sort it on the Grafana level:

There can be multiple options, but IMHO [Join transformation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#join-by-field) is the best option. You need 2 queries (metrics and metadata), which will have common field (e.g `instance_id`), which will be used to join them on the Grafana level.
That metadata query can be implemented in multiple ways. IMHO the easiest way is to use [TestData type datasource](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/testdata/), where you can define `CSV content` (in the right format, e.g. `instance_id,name`) directly on the query level = you don't need to save anything into real TSDB and you can edit it metadata there anytime on the dashboard level (of course you may have different use case where instance_ids are very dynamic and then this "hardcoded" option is not the best one - this is just generic idea how to sort it - real implementation depends on your requirements, which are not published in the question).

Please read Grafana documentation for your particular Grafana version for more details. Provided links are for the latest Grafana version, but you may have different version, where it can have different implementation/names/...